# html simple anchor link doesn't work in opera

Tags: anchor, opera

At first If something similiar to this already has been asked, I am sorry, but that is my first question here and i didn't find anything that could had helped.
Since i dont know if it's important, my doctype is:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<div id="container"> /* container i which everything is nested */
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="Navigation">
<a onmouseover="Bildwechsel('Galerie','HGalerie.png');"onmouseout="Bildwechsel('Galerie','Galerie.png');" href="Galerie.htm"><img alt="Navigation" src="Galerie.png" name="Galerie" /></a> //one of the links which is causing trouble
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

and that is the mouseover function (hope you don't mind the names, i'm German):

```
function Bildwechsel(Bild, BildSource) {

    document.images[Bild].src = BildSource; /* function i use to change pictures on mouseover */
}
```

In my header, i have also included two versions of jQuery (that is because a plugin needs an older version to work properly) and lightbox v2. I have implemented them with  `var something=jQuery.noConflict();`, also inserting `true` in one of these declarations because otherwise it wouldn't work but since everything works fine, I think there shouldn't be a problem.

My problem know is that when i click the link with `href="Galerie.htm"`  every browser I mentioned at the beginning excluding opera (I am using version 11.62) is navigating to `Galerie.htm`. But in Opera it's like the Browser's only refreshing the site, so he always stays on the same page no matter what link i click. Maybe good to know: When i right-click on the link and open it in a new tab, everything works fine.

And the second question is: Although i know what doctypes are good for, how do i know which one is best to use in my case? i already did check my html markup, getting about 50 results(?) with errors like :`link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="something.css" >` missing slash between [...] `.css"` and >, but when i look it up in selfhtml it's written that way. I know that i depends on the doctype if the slash is needed or not ,but do i have to look every single slash up or is it not that important? If yes how can i achieve a valid html with 0 errors?

Since I always thought a (anchor?) links are the last thing i will have problems with I have really no clue whats going on here.
Any help would be appreciated ;)

Comment: Hi, we need a link or demo to investigate this. It's somewhat unlikely that we can help you without seeing the full story.

Answer (score 0):

without firing up Opera and playing with all this myself.. first, in that link you need a space between your onmouseover and onmouseout attributes.

e.g.

```
<a onmouseover="Bildwechsel('Galerie','HGalerie.png'); "onmouseout="Bildwechsel('Galerie','Galerie.png');" href="Galerie.htm"><img alt="Navigation" src="Galerie.png" name="Galerie" /></a> <!-- btw, "//" starts a javascript comment, but not so in HTML.  //one of the links which is causing trouble -->
```

Does that help?

Comment: well sry in the original document i have a space between onmouseover and onmouseout, so that doesn't help but thanks for your help anyway. maybe you can tell me how you would "play with it" as you said since i'm not willing to send you my whole project honestly...

Comment: "play with it" meant try to reproduce the error.  I doubt your whole project will be needed to isolate the issue.  See if you can reproduce the issue under the *simplest* of circumstances (like just with the link alone on an otherwise bare html page).  If the issue does not show, then add in the modules/libraries/features of your project one by one.. and test again.. like that, until you find the culprit.